# Set predefined subject and text for contact form on button click

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, href

I am trying to do the following think but I dont have clue how to work it properly:

On my page products.html I have some products with buttons to Order. This buttons will redirect you to contact form and set some defualt subject and text.

E.g: If I click on "Order computer" I will be redirected to contact page with form and the form will contain filled datas.

Subject: "Computer Order"

Text: "i would like to make a order..."

This is how my button looks like

```
<a class="dc_c3b_large dc_c3b_orange dc_button" href="/contact.html?subject="computer"><span style="font-size:25px !important">OBJEDNAJ!</span></a>
```

And this is my form

```
<form action="contact.php" method="post" id="contactform_main">
...
 <label for="subject">Predmet*</label>
                        <input id="subject" name="subject" class="text"/>
<input type="submit" name="imageField" value="submit" class="send" />
</form>
```

Is that possible just with Html or do i need javascript?

Answer (score 0):

If you were able to use php you would be able to do this. 
As far as using javascript or html I do not believe so.
If you have php enabled use this code on your contact page.

Change your form method to 'get'
In your contact form have 
Something along the lines of this

```
<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" vaule="$_GET["subject"]"/>
```

That should work